# Random decimal leads to negative

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to take a monetary value (using `decimal`) and break it into random parts distributed among 14 different labels that add up to be the original value.

example:   value 50.00

- 1 = 1.50
- 2 = 3.50
- 3 = 7.00
- 4 = .75
- 5 = 1.25
- 6 = 2.00
- 7 = 5.50
- 8 = 6.10
- 9 = .60
- 10 = .50
- 11 = 5.30
- 12 = 3.00
- 13 = 3.00
- 14 = 10.00

(not exact values but random values like that, which will total up to the total)

The problem is that I can't figure out the following:

1. The first of the random numbers is high (if the value is 50 the first number is usually 40 something) and the remaining numbers are low under 5 or so
2. Secondly, the output numbers are not in decimal format - they're all whole numbers
3. Finally, half the numbers are positive and half are negative numbers. It does add up to the number I want, but I do not want negative output.

The code that I am using:

```
 private void generatewins(Decimal amount)
    {
        Decimal initialValue = amount;
        Decimal currentRemainder = amount;
        var values = new List<int>();
        Label[] labels = { win1, win5, win10, win9, win6, win2, win3, win7, win8, win11, win13, win12, win4 };
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Decimal remainingPortion = initialValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        {

            Decimal val = currentRemainder - rnd.Next(14 - i);

            currentRemainder -= val;


            labels[i].Text = Convert.ToString(val) + "";
            win14.Text = currentRemainder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

To clarify some things, the reason that I'm using labels is that I have to place these labels in specific places on the form so that they will change with the form size and with another object on the form. I thought using labels would be easier.  Also, number 14 isn't part of the remainder; it is set to take the leftover from the initial value because when I added it into the randomly split values, it would always come up as 0 and the other 13 values would not sum to the initial amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, to start with problem 2) the reason they are whole numbers is because your random result will be a whole number.  use rnd.NextDouble() instead, this gets a random decimal number between 0 and 1.

that may sound like a bad range but it will be good for solving problem 1) that results start out big and then get small. this is obviously because the random range you are providing changes and shrinks as the loop goes on.  what I would do is simply loop through 14 times (or what ever it is) and get 14 random numbers between 0 and 1.  THEN! add all the numbers up, divide that sum by the total value (50.00 in your case) then go through again and multiply all the numbers by that result.  this will make the numbers add up to the total, and make it so all the numbers have an equal chance of being anything in the range

```
decimal Total = 50.00;
decimal randTotal = 0;
decimal []values = new decimal[14];
for(int i = 0; i<14; i++)
{
    values[i] = rnd.NextDouble();
    randTotal += values[i]
}

decimal co = Total / randTotal;

for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
   values[i] *= co;
```

values will then be an array of random decimal numbers that add up to Total.

then if you want to sort out the rounding (to the nearest cent)
what I would do is the following:

```
decimal leftOver = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<14; i++)
{
   decimal centFraction = values[i] - Math.floor(values[i] * 100) / 100; //floor rounds a number down to the nearest whole number
   values[i]-=centFraction;
   leftOver+=centFraction;
}
//then just add the left over cents (which should be in whole cents!) to one of them
values[0]+=leftOver;
```

this might not be the best way to do it, as it means technically there isn't an even distribution now, but it might do?

P.S.  problem 3 is caused by the fact that you are simply getting 14 random numbers based on ranges that have NOTHING to do with your total.  if your total was $2 you can clearly see that your first call to rnd.Next(14 - i) (get a random number between 0 and 14) could easily result in a number bigger than 2.

Comment: Although everyones answer seemed to provide better output then what I could come up with this example helped alot this is perfect down to the last few decimals and allows me to use the left over for something else which i was going to do once I could get everything to add up thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a loop with something like

```
decimal Total = 50.00M;
for ( i = 0; i <= 14; i++)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    decimal newDec = Math.Round((random.NextDouble(0 , Total) / 100),3));
    //do something to log newDec
    Total -= newDec;
}
```

Comment: Thats where Im having issues I started out almost exactly like that but using the rnd.Next(0,Total) gives me an error assuming because Total isnt an Int.  If i do rnd.Next(0, Convert.ToInt32(Total)); it works but doesnt fully add up to 50 and also makes all the outputs whole numbers

Comment: I see , i'll change answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

The Random class returns integers.  If you want decimal numbers, you can divide by 100.

Also note that the parameter to Next is the size of the random number.  You should limit this to the size of the number that you want.  This is why you are getting negative numbers - If the random number returned is larger than your current remainder, (which can happen whenever (14-i) ends up greater than the current remainder, then the value will come out negative.

With your first number coming out large, think about the possible outcomes of the first iteration.  The random number is somewhere between 0 and 14, so the val result must always be somewhere within 14 less than your original number.  What you actually want is a skewed distribution, where the first val can be anywhere from zero to the original value, but averaging somewhere around (CurrentRemainder/(14-i)).  This will give more random values.  It would take more of a math expert than me to know the optimum distribution that will ensure correctly random numbers, but provided each iteration is guaranteed to be within the range of zero to current remainder, then at least you will not go past the total.  A simple solution would be to restrict the values between 0 and twice the average, like this...

Decimal currentRemainder = initialValue;

```
for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
{
    Decimal avg = (currentRemainder/(14-i));
    Decimal val = currentRemainder - (rnd.Next(avg*2*100)/100);

    currentRemainder -= val;

    labels[i].Text = Convert.ToString(val) + "";
    win14.Text = currentRemainder.ToString();
}
labels[13] = Convert.ToString(currentRemainder);
```

That should get pretty close.  Getting a fully perfect random distribution  will require a lot more maths to tune each value, and that's a bit beyond me.